# Apps dont open after I reopen the laptop lid

Tags: suspend, laptop

When I close the laptop lid (sleep or suspend whatever you call it) and I open that lid, the system doesnt freezes, but no apps open if I clcik the icons. When I shutdown it says somw wierd errors in the black line and doesnt shuts down for 2-3 minutes untill i remove the lapotp battery. After I again open the laptop using power button now it works but its so frustating. Please help me guys!

Comment: /etc/systemd/logind.conf